# IndexError: list index out of range in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a 3D array. I want extract the 3rd element. For example, here I want to print 6, 9, 20. But Python is throwing this error.

```
values = [
    [[0, 6], [0, 9], [0, 20]],
    [[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 9 ]]]
i=0
for j in range(0,len(values[i])):
   print(values[i][i][j])
```

Not sure where this is going wrong because print(values[0][0][1]) works fine and gives 6 as it should

Comment: len of array [0, 6] is 2 long. The elements are adressed with 0 and 1, 2 does not exist.

Comment: I think you want to do this: for j in range(0,len(values[i][i]))

Comment: Yes I want to print 6,9 and 20. ```len(values[0])``` gives 3, not 2, thats where I am confused

Comment: MangoNrFive, I just tried your suggestion, but it prints out 0 and 6 only

Answer (score 1):

in here `len(values[i])` is 3 hence the `range(0, len(values[i])` gives you values 0,1,2 and the length of [0,6] is 2 and you cant access element with index 2

hence it gives you index out of range error

Answer (score 0):

The value of j in `for j in range(0,len(values[i]))` become 0,1,2 but when value of j is 2 and run `values[i][i][j]` and `i=0` the code run `values[0][0][2]` and this is out of range value for [0,6]

to print 6, 9, 20. can use this block of code:

```py
values = [[[0, 6], [0, 9],[ 0, 20]], [[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 9]]]
for j in range(len(values[0])):
    print(values[0][j][1])
```